# Can't have my data from firebase after get method with reactjs

Tags: reactjs, firebase

Hello i take data from realtime database in firebase with this way.

```
         useEffect(() => {
                   async function asyncCall() {
                           const myurl = await axios.get("https://mysiteproject- 8adcf.firebaseio.com/products.json")
                           setUrl(myurl)
         }
         asyncCall();

         },[]);
```

The result of when i

```
 console.log(url)
```

showing in the below image

[image]

When i

```
  console.log(url.data)
```

this is shown up

[image]

That is the data i want to map. But when i

```
 console.log(url.data.id)
```

this is shown up in my console

[image]

Can anyone tell me why this happening.
Also i try this in my code

```
       useEffect(() => {
    async function asyncCall() {
        const myurl = await axios.get("https://mysiteproject-8adcf.firebaseio.com/products.json")
            setUrl(myurl)
    }
    asyncCall();

},[]);

let myvar = url.data;
console.log(myvar);
{myvar.map((myvar => (
    console.log(myvar.id)
)))}
```

But again i have a error

[image]

Can anyone help me with this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add check if `url.data` is exists. When you render `console.log(myvar);` - `url.data` is undefined because you didn't get it from the server yet. So your code should looks like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
  async function asyncCall() {
    const myurl = await axios.get(
      "https://mysiteproject-8adcf.firebaseio.com/products.json"
    );
    setUrl(myurl);
  }
  asyncCall();
}, []);

if (url.data) {
  let myvar = url.data;
  console.log(myvar);
  myvar.map((myvar) => console.log(myvar.id));
}
```

When you'll get `url.data` the component will be updated because you update state via `setUrl` and the data will be logged to console.